# How to migrate app state from React Context to Redux Tool Kit?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-context, redux-toolkit

**What I'm trying to achieve:**

I have a NextJS + Shopify storefront API application. Initially I set up a Context api for the state management but it's not that efficient because it re-renders everything what's wrapped in it. Thus, I'm moving all  state to the Redux Toolkit.

Redux logic is pretty complex and I don't know all the pitfalls yet. But so far I encounter couple problems. For example in my old Context API structure I have **couple functions** that take a **couple arguments**:

```
    const removeFromCheckout = async (checkoutId, lineItemIdsToRemove) => {
        client.checkout.removeLineItems(checkoutId, lineItemIdsToRemove).then((checkout) => {
            setCheckout(checkout);
            localStorage.setItem('checkout', checkoutId);
        });
    }

    const updateLineItem = async (item, quantity) => {
        const checkoutId = checkout.id;
        const lineItemsToUpdate = [
            {id: item.id, quantity: parseInt(quantity, 10)}
        ];
        client.checkout.updateLineItems(checkoutId, lineItemsToUpdate).then((checkout) => {
            setCheckout(checkout);
        });
    }
```

One argument (`checkoutId`) from the state and another one (`lineItemIdsToRemove`) extracted through the `map()` method.
Inside actual component in JSX it looks and evokes like this:

```
<motion.button 
    className="underline cursor-pointer font-extralight"
    onClick={() => {removeFromCheckout(checkout.id, item.id)}}
>
```

**How can I declare this type of functions inside createSlice({ }) ?**
Because the only type of arguments reducers inside createSlice can take are `(state, action)`.
**And also is it possible to have several useSelector() calls inside one file?**

I have two different 'Slice' files  imported to the component:

```
    const {toggle} = useSelector((state) => state.toggle);
    const {checkout} = useSelector((state) => state.checkout);
```

and only the {checkout} gives me this error:
`TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'checkout' of 'Object(...)(...)' as it is undefined.`

Thank you for you're attention, hope someone can shad the light on this one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [prepare notation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice#customizing-generated-action-creators) for that:

```
const todosSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'todos',
  initialState: [] as Item[],
  reducers: {
    addTodo: {
      reducer: (state, action: PayloadAction<Item>) => {
        state.push(action.payload)
      },
      prepare: (id: number, text: string) => {
        return { payload: { id, text } }
      },
    },
  },
})

dispatch(todosSlice.actions.addTodo(5, "test"))
```

But 99% of the cases you would probably stay with the one-parameter notation and just pass an object as payload, like

```js
dispatch(todosSlice.actions.addTodo({ id: 5, text: "test"}))
```

as that just works out of the box without the prepare notation and makes your code more readable anyways.